# Parallelism of Streams in Spark Streaming Context

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have multiple input sources (~200) coming in on Kafka topics - the data for each is similar, but each must be run separately because there are differences in schemas - and we need to perform aggregate health checks on the feeds (so we can't throw them all into 1 topic in a simple way, without creating more work downstream). I've created a spark app with a spark streaming context, and everything seems to be working, except that it is only running the streams sequentially. There are certain bottlenecks in each stream which make this very inefficient, and **I would like all streams to run at the same time - is this possible**? I haven't been able to find a simple way to do this. I've seen the concurrentJobs parameter, but that doesn't worked as desired. Any design suggestions are also welcome, if there is not an easy technical solution.

Thanks

Comment: I am using the 'direct' streams from 1.3.1

Comment: could you add some code illustrating how you're dealing with the topics? sounds like a `foreach` there.

Comment: from the sound of it, you'd probably be better off with separate jobs for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/job-scheduling.html
with the fairscheduler.xml file.

By default it is FIFO... it only worked for me once I explicitly wrote the file (couldn't set it programmatically for some reason).